# Why HRV is considered as "irregularly time-sampled sequence"?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, sampling

HRV is heart rate variability. As far as I understood, it is the time interval between two consecutive R peaks in the ECG signal. So an HRV dataset may contain two columns, one containing the interval number (1, 2, ...) and the other containing the time of that interval in milliseconds. So why in some articles it is considered as an "irregularly time-sampled sequence"?

Answer (score 1):

> HRV is the time interval between two consecutive R peaks in ECG signal

No, that would be the instantaneous Heart Rate ($\tt{HR}$).

Heart Rate Variability ($\tt{HRV}$) **is the physiological variation of that interval** (i.e. of the heart rate). Since the heart rate fluctuates, so does the relative location of successive R-peaks in an ECG signal. Therefore, a dataset with the interval *number* (or beat number) in one column and the corresponding RR interval *time* in the other column is indeed an "irregularly time-sampled sequence", since that second column contains information recorded when a R-peak is detected. **That sequence is heart-rate dependent, hence irregular.**

---

There are multiple different ways to compute the $\tt{HRV}$ from the sequence of RR intervals, both in time-domain and frequency domain. The most straightforward is through the sequence's **[standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)**:

$$\texttt{HRV} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(\tt{RR}_k - \overline{\tt{RR}})^2}$$
where $N$ is the number of RR intervals recorded, $\tt{RR}$ is the time duration of interval number $k$ and $\overline{\tt{RR}}$ the average RR interval duration.

Comment: Thank you @Jdip , I understand true meaning of HRV now, but it is still vague for me that why it is irregularly time-sampled. In fact RR peaks interval changes, but ...

Comment: Ok, think of it this way: let's say the first R peak is found at location $t_0$, the second at $t_1$ and the third at $t_2$. This defines two RR intervals $[t_0,t_1]$ and $[t_1, t_2]$. Assume the HR has fluctuated, i.e.  $t_2-t_1 \neq t_1-t_0$, then $t_0, t_1$ and $t_2$ define a sequence that's irregularly sampled. If $t_2-t_1 = t_1-t_0$, then that's regularly sampled (but $\tt{HRV}$ would be $0$).